# Clion: Кириллица отображается лишь в режиме отладки

Tags: c++, консоль, отладка, кириллица, clion

[image: Настройка кодировки]
[image: не работает]
[image: с функциями]
[image: без функций]

Здравстуйте, вознакла такая, довольно странная проблема: Clion напрочь отказывается понимать кириллицу, причем как на ввод, так и на вывод, пока я не запускаю код через Debugger. В VS такой проблемы не наблюдается.
В свою очередь через debug прекрасно считывает и выводит русский текст, даже когда отключены setlocale и setConcole
Вывод через debug заработал, когда выставил везде 1251 кодировку. До этого, не важно через что запускал и с какими доп. аргументами, всегда выдавал билеберду
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Хотите, чтобы Вашей проблемой занялись - тогда код нужно вставлять не картинкой, а текстом, который можно скопировать в свою среду отладки. Вы бы почитали правила форума.

Answer (score 0):

Странно вы русский язык включаете.
Почему второй аргумент `setlocale` есть `rus`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Лол";
}
```

Вот так все работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но, к сожалению, не помогло, вывод остался таким же, как и в первом случае

Answer (score 0):

help -> find_action -> registry -> отключить run.processes.with.pty

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).